# Iterating through lists to create XML nodes

Tags: python-3.x, xml, nested-lists

I am parsing a large XML file to create 2 lists (channelName & channelNum), and the creation of these lists is working.
What I am trying to do next is create a new, smaller XML file based on the lists created, with a separate child node () for each set of channel names and channel numbers.

The lists created from the code below (shortened here) are:

```
channelName = ['Channel 01', 'Channel 02', 'Channel 03', 'FOX', 'NBC', 'Channel 04']
channelNum = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

The code I have tried is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('svd_guide.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

ChannelName = []
ChannelNum = []

for child in root.findall('channel'):
    ChannelName.append(child.find('name').text)
    ChannelNum.append(child.find('logicalChannel').text)

def create_xml():
    channelroot = ET.Element("channels")
    child = ET.SubElement(channelroot, "channel")

    for name, num in zip(ChannelName, ChannelNum):
        ET.SubElement(child, "name").text = name
        ET.SubElement(child, "chan").text = num

    guidetree = ET.ElementTree(channelroot)

    guidetree.write("guide.xml", encoding = "utf-8", xml_declaration = True)    

create_xml()
```

The results I get are:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?\>  
<channels>
    <channel>
        <name>Channel 01</name>
        <chan>1</chan>
        <name>Channel 02</name>
        <chan>2</chan>
        <name>Channel 03</name>
        <chan>3</chan>
        <name>FOX</name>
        <chan>4</chan>
        <name>NBC</name>
        <chan>5</chan>
        <name>Channel 04</name>
        <chan>6</chan>
   </channel>
</channels>
```

The results I was hoping to get are:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?\>  
<channels>
    <channel>
        <name>Channel 01</name>
        <chan>1</chan>
    </channel>
    <channel>
        <name>Channel 02</name>
        <chan>2</chan>
    </channel>
    <channel>
        <name>Channel 03</name>
        <chan>3</chan>
    </channel>
    <channel>
        <name>FOX</name>
        <chan>4</chan>
    </channel>
    <channel>
        <name>NBC</name>
        <chan>5</chan>
    </channel>
    <channel>
        <name>Channel 04</name>
        <chan>6</chan>
   </channel>
```

Comment: Can you remove all those `\` from the XMLs, or do you really want/need those in the results?  Also, some formatting of this XML would be nice, to make your question more readable.

Comment: Also, please remove those backslashes. That will greatly help us to help you.

Comment: @HaiVu: Sorry, the `\\` where missing from my comment, I had to type two of them to make 1 appear.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to move `child = ET.SubElement(channelroot, "channel")` to inside the for-loop, because you want/need to create a `channel` multiple times.

I changed some other parts, because I do not have a `svd_guide.xml`, so I used an init on the `ChannelName` and `ChannelNum`.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#tree = ET.parse('svd_guide.xml')
#root = tree.getroot()

ChannelName = ['Channel 01', 'Channel 02', 'Channel 03', 'FOX', 'NBC', 'Channel 04']
ChannelNum = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

#for child in root.findall('channel'):
#    ChannelName.append(child.find('name').text)
#    ChannelNum.append(child.find('logicalChannel').text)

def create_xml():
    channelroot = ET.Element("channels")
    #child = ET.SubElement(channelroot, "channel")

    for name, num in zip(ChannelName, ChannelNum):
        child = ET.SubElement(channelroot, "channel")
        ET.SubElement(child, "name").text = name
        ET.SubElement(child, "chan").text = num
        

    guidetree = ET.ElementTree(channelroot)

    guidetree.write("guide.xml", encoding = "utf-8", xml_declaration = True)    

create_xml()
```

output (`guide.xml`):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<channels>
    <channel/>
    <channel>
        <name>Channel 01</name>
        <chan>1</chan>
    </channel>
    <channel>
        <name>Channel 02</name>
        <chan>2</chan>
    </channel>
    <channel>
        <name>Channel 03</name>
        <chan>3</chan>
    </channel>
    <channel>
        <name>FOX</name>
        <chan>4</chan>
    </channel>
    <channel>
        <name>NBC</name>
        <chan>5</chan>
    </channel>
    <channel>
        <name>Channel 04</name>
        <chan>6</chan>
    </channel>
</channels>
```